# metodo o codigo en android para saber si la llamada paso a buzon de voz

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy buscando por medio de programación en android saber cuando una llamada es rechazada o cuando una llamada es enviada al buzón de voz.

tambien estoy buscando como puedo saber cuando la llamada es conectada con el proveedor de servicio telefonico

Comment: Bienvenido. Juan., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que podemos hacer es obtener cuando esta sonando el telefono y no se atiende , cuando estas marcando un numero o cuando cancelas la llamada, y para obtener el numero que mando el mensaje de voz podrias usar `getVoiceMailNumber()` de [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager) (puede no funcionar para todos los proveedores)

Este requiere el permiso `READ_PHONE_STATE` en tu manifest, como lo detalla [AQUI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getVoiceMailNumber())

Para implementar lo primero y saber cuando pierdes una llamada, cuando esta sonando o cuando estas marcando podemos hacer lo siguiente

Creamos una clase que es un listener que escucha cuando pasa alguna de estas cosas, llamada perdida, llamada en curso, o atendiendo una llamada

```
 int prev_state=0;


  public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {  

        private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";  

        @Override  
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){  

            if(incomingNumber!=null&&incomingNumber.length()>0) incoming_nr=incomingNumber;   

            switch(state){  
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:  
                        Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_RINGING");  
                        prev_state=state;  
                        break;  
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  
                Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");  
                prev_state=state;  
                break;  
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:  
                    Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDLE==>"+incoming_nr);  
                    NumberDatabase database=new NumberDatabase(mContext);  
                    if((prev_state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)){  
                        prev_state=state;  
                        //Llamada contestada que termino
                    }  
                    if((prev_state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)){  
                        prev_state=state;  
                        //Llamada cancelada o perdida  
                    }  
                    break;  

            }  
        }  
    }
```

> CALL_STATE_RINGING

Se llama cuando el telefono esta sonando

> CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK

Se llama cuando estamos marcando algu numero

> CALL_STATE_IDLE

Se llama cuando se rechaza una llamada o no se atiende

Luego debes hacer una clase que extienda a `BrodcastReceiver` para obtener estos datos con un metodo `onReceive()`

```
public class IncomingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); //TelephonyManager objecto 
        CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();  
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);          //Registramos nuestro listener con TelephonyManager  

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();  
        String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");  

        mContext=context; 

}
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: -1 sin comentar por que ?